# DeviceInfo native module is not installed correctly when running two applications

Tags: android, react-native

I have two similar React-Native applications for Android.

I started them independently on different computers and they work well, but when I started them both on the same computer with `react-native run-android`, I got in the Android emulator:

```
DeviceInfo native module is not installed correctly
```

Now, I'm trying to stop one of them but I don't know how.

I ran `react-native eject` in both their home directories, but that gave me `Both the iOS and Android folders already exist! Please delete 'ios' and/or 'android' before ejecting.`. I don't understand what this means. I would just like to stop the application from running on an emulator, I don't want to delete any files.

Then I ran `ps | grep react-native` and killed all those processes.

However, the error persists.

Any idea how to get rid of this error?
Or at least, how to stop one of the applications?

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the node_modules, android, and ios directory.
2. run npm install
3. then fire your eject command.